Realtek HD Audio - Microsoft Surface Laptop 2
I really want to use Linux as my daily driver on my Surface Laptop 2. But there is one thing that is bothering me. I've tried the Linux-Surface kernel, to get the touchscreen and basically all the things to work. But the audio is terrible, it's mostly treble with very little bass. On W11 the audio is fine and sounds amazingly well, but on Ubuntu the audio sounds like old laptop speakers 17 years ago.
I've also tried Easy Effects, and it worked pretty well, but still not close enough. And at some videos I watch the bass crackle (like the sound of broken speakers).
Does anyone have any idea how I can fix this? Keep in mind, I am not an advanced user so I would need a dumbed down version of support :)
(Intel Core i5-8250U - Intel UHD Graphics 620 \ Omnisonic Speakers - Intel Audio/Realtek HD Audio SST)
I appreciate it!

Please also open a bug report at the linux surface github
